# What's the implication of protected keywords in class definition in Scala?

Tags: scala, class, generics, covariance, protected

I'm learning Scala by working the exercises from the book "Scala for the Impatient". One exercise asks that:

> The file [Stack.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stack.scala) contains the definition `class Stack[+A]
>   protected (protected val elems: List[A])`
>
> Explain the meaning of the `protected` keywords.

Can someone help me understand this? `protected` obviously makes sense for member variables but what implication does it have in a class definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala, writing

```
class Stack[+A](elems: List[A])
```

also implements a default constructor. If you know Java, then in Java this would be something like

```
class Stack<A> {
    private List<A> elems; 
    public Stack<A>(List<A> elems){this.elems = elems;}
}
```

Now, you have two `protected` keywords in your example:

- `protected val elems: List[A]`
- `protected (/*...*/)`

The first makes the variable `elems` protected, meaning it can only be accessed (and shadowed) by subclasses of `Stack[+A]`.

The second makes the constructor protected, meaning that a new `Stack` instance can only be created by subclasses of `Stack[+A]`.

Again, the equivalent Java code would be something like

```
class Stack<A> {
    protected List<A> elems; 
    protected Stack<A>(List<A> elems){this.elems = elems;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What's the meaning of `+A`?

Comment: It means that `Stack` is covariant in the generic parameter `A`, meaning that `Stack[Dog]` is a `Stack[Animal]`. If you don't add the plus sign, then the assignment `val x: Stack[Animal] = Stack[Dog](Dog("Pluto"))` is illegal.

Comment: Yeah in Java, `List<Dog>` is not `List<Animal>`. So contravariance is `-A` then? If that's so, I guess one could write `class Stack[+A](elems: List[-A])`?

Comment: Yes, contravariance is denoted by the minus sign. However, if I am not mistaken, the variance indicator only appears when declaring a class (or trait), so writing `class Stack[+A](elems: List[-A])` is actually not allowed. If you want to express that `elems` can be a `List` of any supertype of `A`, then you'd probably write `class Stack[+A, B >: A](elems: List[B])`, where `[B >: A]` is like saying `<B super A>` in Java (and `[B <: A]` like saying `<B extends A>`)

Comment: Excellent. Covariance-contravariance is such an important concept but with the Scala syntactic sugar that I'm new to, it's easy to miss the point.
Thanks again.